# Как убрать фокус с перекрытого фрагмента?

Tags: android

В приложении я использую активность и три фрагмента. Фрагменты добавляю при помощи метода add(container, fragment, tag) и использую backStack(null). Ожидалось, что второй добавленный фрагмент (имеет прозрачную рамку) перекроет первый и снимет с него фокус. На деле же я могу использовать видимый интерфейс первого фрагмента (через прозрачную рамку второго), то есть он реагирует если клацать на частично скрытые виджеты и получается каша в виде слоев из нескольких фрагментов. Подскажите как решить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так и должно происходить. Если у второго фрагмента фон прозрачный и пропускает клики - задний фрагмент будет виден и он будет кликабелен.

Решить можно по разному:

1. Использовать `replace` вместо `add`
2. Вместе с `add` второго фрагмента вызывать `hide` для первого.
3. Сделать фон второго фрагмента не пропускающим клики дальше (`android:clickable="true"`)